# Excel VBA - Setting Visibility of PivotItems Error

Tags: excel, filter, powerpoint, pivot-table, vba

I am using the following code to filter a pivot-table in excel (but from powerpoint) - I manage to clear the filters for the "Date" field, but I am having trouble with setting the visibility of the `oPi` values.

```
Sub Data()

Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim oPi As PivotItem
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
oExcel.Workbooks.Open ("\\A79APBRSFACTD\MDSS\FactivityServer\FactShar\OEE_Daily2.xls")
oExcel.Visible = True
Set oExcel = Excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks("OEE_Daily2.xls")

oWB.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").Select
oExcel.Run ("Update_OEE_Daily")
oWB.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").Range("B3").Select

oWB.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date").Orientation = xlHidden

With oWB.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each oPi In .PivotItems
        If oPi.Value <> "7/1/2013" Then
            oPi.Visible = False 'Offending Line
        End If
    Next oPi
End With

Set oExcel = Nothing
Set oWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

The error I receive is `Run-time error '1004': unable to set the visible property of the PivotItem` for the line `oPi.Visible = False`

I have added a watch for `oPi.Value` and `oPi.Visible` and stepped through the code - The line gets stuck at setting the visibility of `oPi.Value = 4/26/2013` and I have found that when I hover over the line, I see `oPi.Visible = <Type Mismatch>` as below:

[image: oPi.Visible = <Type mismatch>]

In the place of `False`, I have tried using `0`, and `CBool(0)`, but all to no avail!
Any help on solving this matter, and allowing the visibility to be changed, will be greatly appreciated!